# Converting from c to AVR assembly help regarding output

Tags: gcc, assembly, arduino, avr

I'm attempting to convert an arduino sketch to avr assembly. Taking it one chunk at a time. Below is what I have so far in an attempt to set up the column and row pins as output. I'm using the atmega168 pin mapping diagram to get the ports. I have wires ran from pins 2-13, and analog 2-5. The program works in the arduino sketch. How do I differentiate between PB3 and PD3 when writing to the pins? Am I on the right track?

```
;const int columnPins[] = { 6,11,10,3,17,4,8,9 };
;const int rowPins[] = { 2,7,19,5,13,18,12,16 };


;void setup() {
;   //int i;    
;   //for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++)
;   //{
;   //  pinMode(rowPins[i], OUTPUT); // make all the LED pins outputs
       ;A0=14, A1=15, A2=16 A3=17 A4 =18 A5=19  
        ;set up rows for output
        PORTD pin 6     ;digital pin 6 on arduino is PD6    
        PORTB pin 3     ;digital pin 11 on arduino is PB3
        PORTB pin 2     ;digital pin 10 on arduino is PB2
        PORTD pin 3     ;digital pin 3 on arduino is PD3
        PORTC pin 3      ;pin 17 on arduino is A3 OR PC3
        PORTD pin 4     ;digital pin 4 on arduino is PD4
        PORTB pin 0     ;digital pin 8 on arduino is PB0
        PORTB pin 1     ;digital pin 9 on arduino is PB1 

        //pinMode(columnPins[i], OUTPUT);
        ;set up columns for output
        PORTD pin 2     ;digital pin 2 on arduino is PD2    
        PORTD pin 7     ;digital pin 7 on arduino is PD7
        PORTC pin 5      ;pin 19 on arduino is A5 OR PC5
        PORTD pin 5     ;digital pin 5 on arduino is PD5
        PORTB pin 5     ;digital pin 13 on arduino is PB5 
        PORTC pin 4      ;pin 18 on arduino is A4 OR PC4
        PORTB pin 4     ;digital pin 12 on arduino is PB4
        PORTC pin 2      ;pin 16 on arduino is A2 OR PC2  




        digitalWrite(columnPins[i], HIGH); // disconnect column pins from Ground
     }
}
```

Could I just do

```
DDRB = 0b11111111; //make all B ports output
DDRC = 0b11111111;
```

then

```
PORTB=0b111111111;
PORTC=0b111111111;
```

to light up the entire thing?

=============================== Updated Code ===============================

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define BLINK_DELAY_MS 1000

int main (void)
{
    DDRB |= 0xFF;       // everbody output!
    DDRD |= 0xFF;
    DDRC |= 0xff;

while(1) {
  /* set pin 5 high to turn led on */
  PORTB |= _BV(PORTB5);
  //PORTB |= _BV(PORTB3);
  //PORTD |= _BV(PORTD6);
  //PORTB |= _BV(PORTB2);
  //PORTD |= _BV(PORTD3);
  //PORTC |= _BV(PORTC3);       /* set pin 3 of portC for output arduino pin A3*/
  //PORTD |= _BV(PORTD4);       /* set pin 4 of PORTD for output arduino pin 4*/ 
  //PORTB |= _BV(PORTB0);           /* set pin 0 of PORTB for output arduino pin 8*/
  //PORTB |= _BV(PORTB1);   

  //column
/*  PORTD |= _BV(PORTD2);  //col8
  PORTD |= _BV(PORTD7);  //col7
  PORTC |= _BV(PORTC5);  //col6
  PORTD |= _BV(PORTD5);  //col5
  PORTB |= _BV(PORTB5);  //col4 
  PORTC |= _BV(PORTC4);  //col3
  PORTB |= _BV(PORTB4);  //col2
  PORTC |= _BV(PORTC2);  //col1
*/
  PORTD |= _BV(0x00);  //col8
  PORTD |= _BV(0x18);  //col7
  PORTC |= _BV(0x3C);  //col6
  PORTD |= _BV(0x7E);  //col5
  PORTB |= _BV(0xFF);  //col4 
  PORTC |= _BV(0xFF);  //col3
  PORTB |= _BV(0x66);  //col2
  PORTC |= _BV(0x00);  //col1


//unsigned char row_val[8]={0x01,0x02,0x04,0x08,0x10,0x20,0x40,0x80};
//unsigned char col_val[8]={0x00,0x66,0xff,0xff,0x7e,0x3c,0x18,0x00};
 }
}
```

Comment: That's C, not assembly.

Comment: Have you tried `avr-objdump -d ...` on the `.elf` file that Arduino IDE produces when you verify the sketch? Is it close to what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm attempting to convert an arduino sketch to avr assembly.

Its somewhat unclear to me what you want to achieve. Do you just want to write Arduino library independent code? I never worked with Arduino, but from what I get it abstracts the actual PORTs / PINs and this is why you are confused?

```
DDRB = 0b11111111; //make all B ports output
DDRC = 0b11111111;
PORTB = 0b111111111;
PORTC = 0b111111111;
```

"make all B ports output" - actually you set all PINs on that ONE PORT to output. But it is correct that your code example configures all I/O pins on PORTB and PORTC as outputs and sets them "high".

> How do I differentiate between PB3 and PD3 when writing to the pins?

I don't understand what you are asking here. PB3 and PD3 are actually just preprocessor definitions like

```
#define PB3 3
```

To actually set PIN 3 on PORT B to high you could write

```
PORTB |= (1 << PB3);  // note that PORTB |= (1 << PD3); would do the same since it just performs a 3 bit left shift
```

This would set PIN 3 on PORT D

```
PORTD |= (1 << PD3);
```

Comment: I've been workin on this pretty much all day. I've got it to light up. I've also discovered which of the column pins light up which column. The commented code under columns just above where I write hex values into the "Ports"?? lit up almost the whole board. How would I go about writing those hex values in to get a picture to display?

Comment: _BV is a macro to perform a left shift operation. `#define _BV(bit) (1 << (bit))`. For those 8-Bit ports, it only makes sense to use it with numbers from 0 to 7. Higher values would just shift the "1" out and the result would be 0, doing nothing.